# DllMain freezing When register a COM dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com, regsvr32

I try to register a COM dll named *MixCenter.dll*. I have found out all the dlls which it is dependent on.  When executives its DllMain first time, it freezes and never returns. It seems like a deadlock, but I don't call any `LoadLibrary`, and it never execute to the `DllMain`. Is there other reasons for this situation ? This is what the `DllMain` exactly looks like:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)  
{  
    switch(ul_reason_for_call)   
    {  
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:   
            g_hinstDLL = hModule;  
            LOG(INFO) <<"--------------Begin Logging--------------";  
            return DllEntryPoint((HINSTANCE)hModule, ul_reason_for_call, lpReserved);  
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:   
            break;  
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:   
            break;  
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:   
            LOG(INFO) << "--------------End Logging--------------";  
            break;  
    }   
    return true;  
}
```

I log the whole execution using Dependency Walker, the essential part of the log is:

```
LoadLibraryExW("MixCenter.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "REGSVR32.EXE" at address 0x003920FF by thread 1.  
Loaded "MIXCENTER.DLL" at address 0x10000000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
Loaded "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F250000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
Loaded "D3D9.DLL" at address 0x6C130000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
Loaded "D3D8THK.DLL" at address 0x73490000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
Loaded "D3DX9_40.DLL" at address 0x69B00000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
Loaded "MSVCP80.DLL" at address 0x71430000 by thread 1.  Successfully hooked module.  
DllMain(0x6F250000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCR80.DLL" called by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsAlloc") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F253001 and returned 0x75CE8731 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsGetValue") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F25300E and returned 0x75CE0DC7 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsSetValue") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F25301B and returned 0x75CE2904 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FlsFree") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F253028 and returned 0x75CE2AD7 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F259668 and returned 0x75CE0D2B by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252BBC and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.    
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252C33 and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "EncodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252D3A and returned 0x77603275 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "DecodePointer") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F252D4A and returned 0x775FF050 by thread 1.
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "IsProcessorFeaturePresent") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F26A967 and returned 0x75CE0DD4 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75BC0000 [MSVCRT.DLL], "_set_error_mode") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F254447 and returned 0x75BD4A3D by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75BC0000 [MSVCRT.DLL], "?set_terminate@@YAP6AXXZP6AXXZ@Z") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F254463 and returned 0x75BEEBB7 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75BC0000 [MSVCRT.DLL], "_get_terminate") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F25447F and returned NULL by thread 1. Error:  (127).
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "FindActCtxSectionStringW") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F251DBE and returned 0x75CE18F9 by thread 1.  
GetProcAddress(0x75C90000 [KERNEL32.DLL], "GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW") called from "MSVCR80.DLL" at address 0x6F251F1A and returned 0x75CE0E64 by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x6F250000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCR80.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x73490000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3D8THK.DLL" called by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x73490000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3D8THK.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x6C130000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3D9.DLL" called by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x6C130000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3D9.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x69B00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3DX9_40.DLL" called by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x69B00000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "D3DX9_40.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x71430000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCP80.DLL" called by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x71430000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCP80.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.  
DllMain(0x10000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "MIXCENTER.DLL" called by thread 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of things you can't do in `DllMain`.  Not only can you not call `LoadLibrary` yourself, but you can't do anything which would cause `LoadLibrary` to be called, and registering a COM server sounds like it might easily do a `LoadLibrary` at some point.

But this is not the extent of what you can't do in `DllMain`.  The list is long and complex, so the best thing to do is often to use a 2-phase initialization scheme, in which `DllMain` simply sets a flag and then some other code within your DLL will do the complex initialization.  This "other code"  might be another thread withing your DLL, or it might just be an `Init()` function you call from your DLL's main routines when they are invoked.

Comment: Under your guidance, I found out parts of the DllMain prohibited list: 1. can't call into User32. 2. can't use CRT memory management with dynamic link library. Guess this can explain the strange situation.